# Add custom.css to SharePoint 2016 masterpage

Tags: master-page, css, 2016

anyone idea how to add custom CSS file to SharePoint 2016.

2013 way `"<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="/Style Library/css/customized.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />"` not working.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless what's the way that you are using, but the following steps should be working in SharePoint 2016

- Upload your custom CSS file to `Style Library` or `Site Assets`
- Go to site setting > Look and Feel > Design Manager > Publish and Apply Design > Assign Master Page based on device channel .

[image]

- At Alternate CSS URL > `Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:` > Browse your file.
- Check `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL` if you need to apply this for all Subsite.

[image]

**[Update]**

After I updated your question, you were missing the format of code. so I found out you are using `SharePoint:CssRegistration` , So try to use it as the following

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/css/customized.css %&gt;" runat="server"  />
```

Or

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/css/customized.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />
```

For more details check [Starter Master Pages for SharePoint 2016](http://blog.drisgill.com/2016/04/starter-master-pages-sharepoint-2016.html)

Comment: Still not working :( I dont have enabled Publishing infrastructure feature.

Comment: My fault: Now working perfect. 
`<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="/SiteAssets/custom.css" runat="server" after="corev15.css" />`